# Cannot compile c# project using a MySql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, ubuntu-20.04

I am attempting to add a MySql connection to my c# program.  I have followed the instruction in the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-unix.html)

Checking in `/usr/lib/mono/gac/` I can see that MySql.Data has been successfully registered. Yet when I try to compile:

```
mcs -r:MySql.Data.dll MainForm.cs
```

I get the following error:

```
error CS0006: Metadata file `MySql.Data.dll' could not be found
```

When I download the connector there are two directories in the zip file each containing a *MySql.Data.dll* file:

- v4.8
- v4.5.2

I have registered each of these and had no success with either. I tried v4.8 first and when it didn't work, I removed it and registered v4.5.2

Some more information:

- OS -> Ubuntu 20.04
- Downloaded most recent MySql connector [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, but I'd personally skip Mono, and go straight to .NET 5.0 https://dot.net/. `dotnet add package MySqlConnector && dotnet build` and you should be good to go. (Do you need to solve your problem using Mono, or would any .NET runtime on Ubuntu be sufficient?)

Answer (score 0):

I used the absolute path for `MySql.Data.dll` and it worked for me

```
mono-csc -r:/usr/lib/mono/gac/MySql.Data/5.2.1.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll form.cs
```